# How do I implement properly a servlet using OSGi declarative services?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, osgi, declarative-services

I'm trying (to learn how) to create a Servlet (`javax.servlet.Servlet`) using declarative services (DS), provided by OSGi, as below:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Servlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(service = Servlet.class, property = { "alias:String=/hello" }, immediate = true)
public class LogsHTTPServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2302372200114479484L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("It works!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        resp.setStatus(200);
    }
}
```

When I run [the project](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/org.example.osgidsservlet) on [Eclipse](https://download.eclipse.org/equinox/) <sup>(2019-03 (4.11.0), build id: 20190314-1200)</sup> upon [this target platform](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/org.example.osgidsservlet/blob/master/resources/openhab.target), using a [custom run configuration](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/org.example.osgidsservlet/blob/master/resources/OSGi%20Framework%20(Custom).launch), where I set up `org.eclipse.jetty.server` (and other required dependencies) with [this VM argument](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/org.example.osgidsservlet/blob/eae64899592ffaa2160291f1723360bcc17fd6b2/resources/OSGi%20Framework%20(Custom).launch#L18) (`-Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=8080`), I see something like below in the osgi console:

```
osgi> 2019-05-07 18:22:28.236:INFO::Start Level: Equinox Container: 0d7d3d67-401b-48eb-b016-6e6c0c16352c: Logging initialized @1590ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2019-05-07 18:22:28.388:INFO:oejs.session:Start Level: Equinox Container: 0d7d3d67-401b-48eb-b016-6e6c0c16352c: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2019-05-07 18:22:28.388:INFO:oejs.session:Start Level: Equinox Container: 0d7d3d67-401b-48eb-b016-6e6c0c16352c: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2019-05-07 18:22:28.389:INFO:oejs.session:Start Level: Equinox Container: 0d7d3d67-401b-48eb-b016-6e6c0c16352c: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
2019-05-07 18:22:28.427:INFO:oejs.session:Start Level: Equinox Container: 0d7d3d67-401b-48eb-b016-6e6c0c16352c: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
```

Now, when I perform this request using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) (`http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello`) I get:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Error 404 ProxyServlet: /hello</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /hello. Reason:

            <pre>    ProxyServlet: /hello</pre>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.15.v20190215</a>
        <hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**How can I solve this issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `alias` use the **`osgi.http.whiteboard.servlet.pattern`** property:

```
@Component(service = Servlet.class, property = {"osgi.http.whiteboard.servlet.pattern=/hello/*" })
```

Alternatively, with the current osgi compendium dependency (version 7.0.0), you can use the `@org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.propertytypes.HttpWhiteboardServletPattern` annotation like this:

```
@Component(service=Servlet.class)
@org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard.propertytypes.HttpWhiteboardServletPattern("/hello/*")
```

See https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.http.whiteboard.html#service.http.whiteboard-i21223311

Comment: Table with all properties is here: https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.http.whiteboard.html#service.http.whiteboard.servlet.properties.table